# Selectively Apply JPA Repository BootstrapMode in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 2.4 project that uses spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency. I see that Spring Boot sets the JPA repository boot strap mode to deferred by default. This is nice as my app is containerized and I want fairly fast startup. However, I have one JPA repository that I need bootstrapped earlier as a query it uses is needed in the initialization logic of another bean. Is there a way to selectively apply the bootstrap mode per repository?

Comment: This is not per repository this is per Entity Manager.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMartinelli . So effectively, I'd need to setup a separate EntityManager for the repository that needs to be bootstrapped early and programmatically configure that behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by earlier?